# DLL project name is left in it's executable file

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a project which consists of several parts, one of them is a DLL that the main program loads at runtime.

Since it's a sensitive thing I am dealing with, I want to make harder for potentional attackers to reverse engineer it.
Now, here's the problem: The DLL file itself contains an ASCII string that contains the name of the project in format `[project name].dll`, located somewhere in the `.text` section.
 According to OllyDbg, it is **never** referenced by the DLL.

I tried turning on/off every setting in VS 2015 that I could think would be causing it, but with no result. Also, I noticed that the same thing happens when you add .def file with some exports to a exe project (exe files don't normally have the string, to my knowledge).

This is an issue because the project name is revealing valuable information to the attacker.

What is it? Is there any way to get rid of it or make it a completely random value instead?

Comment: Obfuscation is never going to give you any real security. Just give it up and stop wasting your time.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I disagree; obfuscation is pretty much the only form of security you can have when the software is running on the attacker's machine. Of course *by definition* it cannot be reliable, but it can go a long way as a dissuasion against low-profile attackers - which are typically the vast majority, are not particularly skilled, and, most importantly, aren't willing to spend *that* much time and effort for your product. After all, if I have to spend €500 worth of time in cracking your product and a regular license would cost €100, probably I'd think this twice.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [LIBRARY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30fw19zw.aspx) setting in the .def file to change the embedded name.

That may change the filename that link.exe creates, but filenames can be changed after the fact.  Anyway, the filename would link this sensitive information of yours, so clearly you are changing that... and then it wouldn't match your import library.  So it's best to set the output filename correctly at the link stage so that the import libraries are correct.